# Convert text file into binary file in c

Tags: c, file-conversion

So I need to convert a text file into a binary file.

The text file in formatted as-

firstname lastname id gpa
(string string unsigned int float)

An example of the text file could be:

jon smith 32 2.5

joe young 12 3.4

```
void textToBinary(char *inp, char *out)
{

FILE *finp;
FILE *fout;
unsigned int x;
float y;
char first[SIZE], last[SIZE];

finp = fopen(inp, "r");
fout = fopen(out, "w");

rewind(finp);

    while(1)
    {
    fscanf(finp, "%s %s %u %f\n", first, last, &x, &y);

    fwrite(first, 1, sizeof(char), fout);
    fwrite(last, 1, sizeof(char), fout);
    fwrite(&x, 4, sizeof(unsigned int), fout);
    fwrite(&y, 4, sizeof(int), fout);

        if(feof(finp))
        {
        break;
        }

    }

 fclose(finp);
 fclose(fout);
}
```

Using the diff command in itsunix I compare the outputted binary file to what the binary file should look like.

```
>diff output.bin b1.bin
>Binary Files output.bin b1.bin differ
```

So this must mean that my text files aren't converting properly to its proper binary file.

Comment: Hint: check `fwrite` parameters, i.e. `size_t fwrite( const void *buffer, size_t size, size_t count, FILE *stream )`, especially the possibility to provide a size and a count separately.

Comment: For both `first` and `last`, why you are recorded only 1 char (`fwrite(first, 1, sizeof(char), fout);`) ?

Comment: What is exactly your problem ? Please read again ["How do I ask a good question?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The provided source code shows misunderstandings about using `fwrite()` function to record data in a binary file.

**Error 1** - to record a string, use a fixed-size or the real length.

Based to both lines `fwrite(first, 1, sizeof(char), fout);` and `fwrite(last, 1, sizeof(char), fout);`.

Use:

```
fwrite(first, (strlen(first)+1), sizeof(char), fout);
```

Or:

```
fwrite(first, SIZE, sizeof(char), fout);
```

**Error 2** - to record only one `unsigned int`, use 1 element.

Based to the line `fwrite(&x, 4, sizeof(unsigned int), fout);`.

Use:

```
fwrite(&x, 1, sizeof(unsigned int), fout);
```

**Error 3** - to record one `float`, use the correct `sizeof()`.

Based to the line `fwrite(&y, 4, sizeof(int), fout);`.

Use:

```
fwrite(&y, 1, sizeof(float), fout);
```

**Extra:**

> In all cases, when using `fwrite()` don't forget to check the returned
>   value (must be equal to the number of elements written).

Comment: Thank you, I had figured out the strlen for the char's but changing the byte amount for float/unsigned int helped